# Extract motion vectors from versatile video coding

Tags: video-processing, h.264, codec, hevc, h.265

How do I go about extracting motion vector into a .txt or .xml file from VVC VTM reference software. I managed to extract the motion vectors to a text file but I don't have a proper index indicating which motion vector belongs where. If anyone could guide me on getting proper index along with motion vectors, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing it at the encoder side?
If so, I suggest that you move to the decoder side and do this:

1. Encode the sequence from which you want to extract MVs.
2. Modify the decoder so it prints the MV of each coding unit, if any (e.g. not intra). To do so, you may go to `CABAC Reader.cpp` file, somewhere inside `coding_unit()` function, and find the place where MV is parsed. There, in addition to the parsed MV, you have access to coordinates of the ongoing CU.
3. Decode your encoded bitstream with the modified VTM decoder and print what you wanted to be printed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @mosen. I managed to get the coordinates of the ongoing CU inside the coding function but MVs are not being parsed inside coding_unit(). They are being parsed lated in mvd_coding() later in the .cpp file and over there I don't have access to the ongoing CU. I would appreciate your input on this. I am trying to extract any meaningful features that I can such as MV, DC coefficients or non zero coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

As Mosen's answer, I recommend you to extract any information(include MVs) from the decoder.

If you just want to extract MVs to file, you may utilize traverseCU().

VTM's picture class has CodingStructure class which traverses all CUs in picture(even CTU or CU can be treated as CodingStructure class, so you can use traverseCU() at block level too).

So I suggest you to

1. Access picture class(its name might be different, e.g., m_pcPic at DecLib.cpp) at the decoder side(insert you code before/after execute loop filters).
2. Iterate each CUs in picutre by using traverseCU().
3. Extract MVs from every CU you accessed, and save those information(MVs, indices, etc.)

Although there might be better ways to answer your question, i hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was on break from research, I just saw this comment. So if i understand correctly, "void DecLib::executeLoopFilters()" is the function before/after which i should add my code? Is this how I should use traverserCUS?: m_pcPic->cs->traverseCUs(CS::getArea( cs, ctuArea, chType ), chType)
    {
       
    } I didn't add the code in the brackets yet, trying to figure that out. I want to extract mvs, dc coefficients, no.of bits spent of coding. Basically any feature i can use to differentiate the background/foreground based on changes in image.

Comment: if you have any suggestion on how to get a no.of pixels in each block that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Your approach is right. You can extract your information by accessing each CU in the picture. By traversing CU, you can access to CU at the area, so you can extract any information of CU. For example, by multiplying lwidth() and lheight() (luma width & height), you can get no. of pixels in CU. You can also access PU(which holds MV info.) or TU(holds transform coef.) through CU.